# Using variables in function names

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my class, we're making a text adventure, and I'm just trying to walk between rooms. So far, I made a class called "Room".

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

As well as some rooms to move between with subclasses.

```
class Backyard(Room):
global current

def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Backyard"

def choose(self,choice):
    if "north" in choice:
        current = kitchen
    else:
        print("You cannot go that way")
    return current

class Kitchen(Room):
    global current

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Kitchen"

    def choose(self,choice):
        if "south" in choice:
            current = yard
        else:
            print("You cannot go that way")
        return current

yard = Backyard()
kitchen = Kitchen()
```

Now, to run the actual game, I have this.

```
run = True
current = yard
show_yard

while run:
    choose(input(">>> ")
    show_current
```

The show_yard function just prints a description of that room (the yard), but when I run the game, I was hoping to be able to use show_current so that whatever the variable 'current' was set to, it would read off that description, but instead it gives me an error because there's no function called 'show_current'.

I'm wondering if there is some way to insert variables when calling a function so that I don't have to write a whole bunch of code for something that could be solved in something as simple as this. Thanks.

Comment: please indent your code, and furthermore, `global` is a serious antipattern. Only in very rare occasions you should use that.

Comment: Give each of your locations a `show()` *method*. Then all you need to use is `current.show()` to call the corresponding method on the current location. You can put the method on the base class (and just use `self.name` to print the name of the location), or give each subclass a more elaborate implementation.

Comment: You don't need to make `current` a global variable everywhere. Your `choose()` methods return the new location, so use `current = current.choose()` to assign returned location back to `current`. Not that setting `global current` *on the class* even works, you can remove the `global current` lines with no change in functionality for your current code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
First, I don't how I didn't properly indent my code, but this is the first question I've posted here.

Second, thanks for the info about the global variable.

Finally, I can't believe I didn't think about using a show() method. I just started using classes, and we haven't even learned them in class yet. So thanks, I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: Alright, update, that worked great, and I cannot express my gratitude enough to all of you guys. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if you add a `show()` method to `Room`, you will be able to call it on every instance of its subclasses:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def show(self):
        print(self.name)
```